# Jquery doesn't recognize click event in one div but anothers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this 4 sections, well there are 3 and 1 footer in my html, and jquery applies a css class when they're clicked, the problem is that the footer which btw is a sticky footer using jquery as well, doesn't recognize even the click event.

```
<div id="principal">

        <section class="rbox" id="left">
            <em>
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            </em>
        </section>

        <section class="rbox" id="top">
            <em>
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
            </em>

        </section>

        <section class="rbox" id="right">
            <em>
                <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
            </em>
        </section>


  </div>
        <footer class="rbox" id="bottom">
            <em>
                <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
            </em>         
        </footer>
```

Here's the js:

```
$(document).on("ready", inicio);
function inicio(){
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    var vwptHeight = $(window).height();

    if(vwptHeight > bodyHeight){
        $("footer#bottom").css("position", "absolute").css("bottom", 0);
    }

    $('.rbox').on("click", despliegue);
    $('footer#bottom').on("click", function(){
        $("footer#bottom").css("background", "red");
    })

};

function despliegue(){
    alert("hola");
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.rbox').removeClass('active');
    }
    else{
        $('.rbox').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
};
```

Another thing is that the alert doesn't show even the function works perfectly but only with the sections the footer not.
What am i doing wrong??
Thanx for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(document).ready(inicio);` instead of `$(document).on('ready',inicio);`

[Your Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NQ9Y/) and [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NQ9Y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

please try the below way to use your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/////^^^^^^^^^^use ready like this way
inicio();
});

function inicio(){
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    var vwptHeight = $(window).height();

    if(vwptHeight > bodyHeight){
        $("footer#bottom").css("position", "absolute").css("bottom", 0);
    }

    $('.rbox').on("click", function(){despliegue});
    $('footer#bottom').on("click", function(){
        $("footer#bottom").css("background", "red");
    });

}

function despliegue(){
    alert("hola");
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.rbox').removeClass('active');
    }
    else{
        $('.rbox').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  tag you can use

```
<div id="footer">Footer Here.</div>
```

and do operation on that like

```
#footer {
```

height: 330px;position: relative;
}